# Concrete 5 - move C5 code, images and references up to docroot

Tags: ftp, content-management-system, web, concrete5

I have installed, configured and built a site on Concrete 5.5.2.1 and it is all working well. I have a problem that I have a URL of `www.ayrshireminis.com/concrete5.5.2.1`, for example, which is where the index.htm file sits. Is there a way that I can bring the code back up to the docroot without breaking all references such as image paths in the database for example?

Considering that the download of Concrete 5 includes this directory I am assuming that this is a common issue for some developers when using this CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible to move the code from a `ROOT/concrete5.5.2.1` directory back to the root *without* running the queries above. I simply moved the code up a directory and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have an "index.htm" file -- there is no such thing in a concrete5 installation. In general, though, you should be able to move the site without problems. A few possible exceptions would be:

- Depending on how exactly you're moving things, make sure you get every folder/file. For example, if you're using SSH and do something like `mv concrete5.5.2.1/* ./`, then you will miss the `.htaccess` file (because it's hidden). But if you're talking about index.htm files I am guessing you're on a Windows server instead of unix so perhaps this doesn't apply.
- In older versions of Concrete5, there was a setting in the `config/site.php` file called `DIR_REL` that you would need to change when you move the site. For example, if moving from the `concrete5.5.2.1` subdirectory up to the top level, you'd change `define('DIR_REL', '/concrete5.5.2.1`);`to`define('DIR_REL', '');`. So take a look in your`config/site.php`file, but if you don't see the`define('DIR_REL'...` line then don't worry about this step.
- If you manually entered full URL's to page links or images, you'll need to update those. Usually this isn't an issue (assuming you use the Concrete5 toolbar that sits above the Rich Text Editor controls -- e.g. "Insert Link to Page", "Insert Image", etc.). But if you notice dead links after you move the site, then either manually update the links by editing the blocks in question, or if you want to make sure you update them all in one fell swoop, you can run the following queries on your database (via PhpMyAdmin, for example):

  ```
  UPDATE btContentLocal SET content = REPLACE(content, '/old/base/dir/', '/new/dir/') WHERE content LIKE '%/old/base/dir/%';
  UPDATE btContentImage SET externalLink = REPLACE(externalLink, '/old/base/dir/', '/new/dir/') WHERE externalLink LIKE '%/old/base/dir/%';
  UPDATE btSlideshowImg SET url = REPLACE(url, '/old/base/dir/', '/new/dir/') WHERE url LIKE '%/old/base/dir/%';
  ```

  ***Be careful with these queries!!*** You will need to change it so `/old/base/dir/` and `/new/dir/` make sense for your particular site. You should absolutely positively back up your database before running these queries otherwise you may **completely and utterly destroy your site** without any way to get it back!!!

Comment: I am on a Linux box, the index.htm file is just the holding page that I put up in the webroot (_Website Coming Soon..._), that may have confused my post. I'm on a free host with ByetHost and as such I don't have SSH access unfortunately, but I am downloading the `concrete5.5.2.1` directory just now, and will upload that once it's finished. I believe `config/site.php` is still in the latest version of Concrete 5 as it's still in the documentation, so I will change this also to reflect the new root (/).

Comment: I notice you have mentioned updating the btContentLocal, btContentImage and btSlideshowImg tables - what about the tables that hold links and other references? For example the table that holds the data for the link to the `contact` page, won't this be expecting to go to `www.ayrshireminis.com/concrete5.5.2.1/contact` for example?

Comment: I'm keen to know if doing something like this would cause Google to index the /concrete5.5.2.1? Or would this be ignored? I'm ahppy to do it this way (as it's quicker and less risk). `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^concrete5.5.2.1/(.+)$ http://www.ayrshireminis.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: The answers you got for your other question about Google indexing seem correct to me ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375384 ). As for the link updates -- no, you do not need to worry about that. Almost every link in the CMS is stored in the database as a relative path or a page id, so it doesn't matter what the top-level directory of the site is. The only exceptions are in rare cases where you've hard-coded full URL's to things in your own content (and these rare cases are what the SQL queries I've posted above are for).