# the Google SEO considerations over using .htaccess rule to ignore top level directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, search-engine, concrete5

I am using the Concrete 5 CMS to build a website and i'd like to push it live.

I have the code in a directory called `/concrete5.5.2.1` and rather than updating the references in the database and moving the code on the filesystem, i'm considering using an .htaccess rule to effectively ignore that directory.

However, I'm keen to know if doing something like this below would mean that Google would index the /concrete5.5.2.1? Or would this be ignored?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^concrete5.5.2.1/(.+)$ http://www.ayrshireminis.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will be just like every other user and only see the URLs you provide. So they will not be aware that directory exists.

Comment: Thanks. The concern is though, that even thought I have .htaccess rewriting these URLs the links on my site will still be pointing to `http://www.ayrshireminis.com/concrete5.5.2.1/contact`, which isn't great. I shouldn't be broadcasting what CMS/framework i'm using for the site. I don't think there's away around that - unless someone can correct me.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use a .htaccess file to have the site show in a different location, simply move the contents of that directory to the root, clear the cache, and re-run the search index job.

You don't have to make any database changes as urls in content are parsed then cached.

Mike

Comment: I am using the Concrete 5 CMS so I believe the references in the database will be an issue for moving the site in this way. I only have FTP access to the server (no SSH), so I am currently uploading the site to the root. Are you familiar with Concrete 5? Have you done something like that before? Does it not require an update of paths in the database?